# Excel 2016 Open specific sheet based on current date

Tags: vba, excel, date

Excel 2016 Workbook with 26 sheets all named Jan 2, Jan 16, Jan 30, Feb 13 and so on. On each sheet cell B1 also has this same information, Jan 2, Jan 16, Jan 30, Feb 13 respectively. On each sheet is also more date information, worksheet Jan 2, B3 has the first date of that week (Jan 2) and then progresses for the two week period Jan 3, Jan 4 Jan 5 ending at M3 Jan 14 only skipping Sundays. I want to have the work book open to the worksheet that has the information about todays date in it. So when I open it on May 19th for instance the worksheet that it is opened to would be May 8.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim mnth As String, dte As String, mday As String 
mday = Now() - Weekday(Now(), 3) 
mnth = Month(mday) 
dte = Day(mday) tabstr = mnth & " " & dte 
For Each ws In Worksheets 
If ws.Name = tabstr Then ws.Select Exit For 
End If 
Next ws
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O! Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code. Take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider. [Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/) or [Mid-Advanced Tutorials](http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/codes-examples-macros-how-tos-most-useful-basics-advanced/) and my [personal favorite](http://analystcave.com/excel-vba-tutorial/)

Comment: Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim mnth As String, dte As String, mday As String

mday = Now() - Weekday(Now(), 3)

mnth = Month(mday)
dte = Day(mday)

tabstr = mnth & " " & dte

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name = tabstr Then
            ws.Select
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

Comment: I tried the above code but I think it is treating it like #'s "1 2" and I need it to see it as "jan 2"

Comment: You're using the wrong function: month() will return the "#" of it, for month as name use [monthname](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/monthname.php)

Comment: `Format(Month(mday),"mmm")` will also work

Comment: I get a Run-time error 13, Type mismatch on your suggestion from Sgdva. I get a compile error on your suggestion Scott

Comment: This works, very inelegant, need a little help to fix it. 

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim mnth As String, dte As String, mday As Date
mday = Now() - Weekday(Now(), 3) - 7
mnth = MonthName(Month(mday), True)
dte = Day(mday)
tabstr = mnth & " " & dte
For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name = tabstr Then ws.Select
Exit For
End If
Next
mday = Now() - Weekday(Now(), 3)
mnth = MonthName(Month(mday), True)
dte = Day(mday)
tabstr = mnth & " " & dte
For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name = tabstr Then
ws.Select
Exit For
End If
Next
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Sub CalendarUpdate()
    ' Created by Brad Tostenson 12/28/2016
    ' Credit "Johnny B"
    ' calendarUpdate Macro

    ' The following code performs 2 basic operations;
    ' OPERATION 1: Opens the Calendar Of Time Off workbook associated with this workbook, updates the information in it and closes it.
' OPERATION 2: Sets the opening page to the current period of time for the Calendar Of Time Off workbook.

' OPERATION 1
' _________________________________________________________________________________
' Turns off alerts so that the user does not receive any dialog boxes
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
' Saves the TimeOff workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
' Opens the Calendar workbook so that it can be updated with the new information
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="S:\Calendar Of Time Off.xltx"

' OPERATION 2
' _________________________________________________________________________________
' variable setup
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim mnth As String, dte As String, mday As Date
' OPERATION 2.1 (Previous week's Monday)
' Finds todays date, from that it finds the previous week's Monday e.g. (if today is Thursday December 29, mday would = December 19)
    mday = Now() - Weekday(Now(), 3) - 7

' OPERATION 2.11 (a portion of this operation is duplicated in operation 2.2)
' Based on the outcome of "mday" it gets the month information and then makes the three letter version = "mnth" e.g. (if mday = December 19, mnth = Dec)
    mnth = MonthName(Month(mday), True)
' Based on the outcome of "mday" it gets the day information and then makes that = "dte" e.g. (if mday = December 19, dte = 19)
    dte = Day(mday)
' Uses the information in "mnth" & "dte" to create a value that will match the syntax used in the naming of the tabs e.g. (Dec 19)
    tabstr = mnth & " " & dte
' The following code uses the "tabstr" (Dec 19) information and will look for a match in the tab names and then opens the workbook to that tab
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name = tabstr Then
            ws.Select
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

' OPERATION 2.2
' Finds todays date, from that it finds the this week's Monday e.g.(if today is Thursday December 29, mday would = December 26)
    mday = Now() - Weekday(Now(), 3)
    mnth = MonthName(Month(mday), True)
    dte = Day(mday)
    tabstr = mnth & " " & dte
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name = tabstr Then
            ws.Select
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
' _________________________________________________________________________________
' OPERATION 1 (CONTINUED)
' Saves the Calendar of Time Off Sheet as a template to avoid file open errors
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="S:\Calendar Of Time Off", FileFormat:=54
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```